# Bluetooth Issues on PopOS 21.04

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, pop-os

I am on PopOS 21.04. Until recently, everything was working perfectly, but after some updates, I could not enable bluetooth from the Settings panel. I tried enabling bluetooth from the command line with `bluetoothctl scan on` and got an error saying the following:

```
$ bluetoothctl scan on
Connection ":1.116" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
```

I added the -d flag to the bluetooth.service's `ExecStart` parameter and got the following debug logs after a coldboot:

```
$ journalctl --unit=bluetooth -f
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/profile.c:ext_adapter_probe() ":1.124/org/bluez/obex/00005005_0000_1000_8000_0002ee000001/00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001" probed
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/adapter.c:adapter_service_add() /org/bluez/hci0
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/sdpd-service.c:add_record_to_server() Adding record with handle 0x10010
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/sdpd-service.c:add_record_to_server() Record pattern UUID 00000003-0000-1000-8000-00805f9
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/sdpd-service.c:add_record_to_server() Record pattern UUID 00000008-0000-1000-8000-00805f9
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/sdpd-service.c:add_record_to_server() Record pattern UUID 00000100-0000-1000-8000-00805f9
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/sdpd-service.c:add_record_to_server() Record pattern UUID 00001002-0000-1000-8000-00805f9
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/sdpd-service.c:add_record_to_server() Record pattern UUID 00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee0
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/adapter.c:adapter_service_insert() /org/bluez/hci0
May 20 10:25:08 nilanjan-mitra bluetoothd[915]: src/adapter.c:add_uuid() sending add uuid command for index 0
```

These are the dmesg logs:

```
$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    6.558671] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.558691] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.558694] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.558696] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.558699] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.704062] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 6 week 12 2021
[    7.781114] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.781117] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.781121] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  285.103971] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  285.103979] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  285.103985] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Also, this is the output of `bluetoothd`:

```
$ bluetoothd
D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.126" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
```

When I run `systemctl restart bluetooth`, bluetooth is switched on but when I turn it off from the Settings panel, I have to restart the service again for bluetooth to turn back on. The BlueZ version is 5.55.

I also rebooted into the recovery partition and performed a clean install, everything was working perfectly up until I ran upgraded the packages with `apt update && apt upgrade`.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or why this is happening? I tried searching for `Connection ":1.126" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies` error but couldn't find anything.

Comment: If everything worked on a clean reinstall and after updating the system it stopped again, it is most certainly a bug (which you should report). You could try downgrading `bluez` to the previous version or editing `bluetooth.conf` yourself.

Comment: I tried BlueZ 5.51, but the same error appears. Have a look: https://imgur.com/a/4aFKyt2

Comment: Please see if any of the steps from [System76's help pages](https://support.system76.com/articles/bluetooth/) can solve the issue. If they don't work, we'll have to dive deeper.

Comment: I actually did try most of the stuff on System76's help section (including the bluetooth page you linked to) prior to asking this question. My findings were as follows:

Bluetooth is neither hard of soft blocked.
The bluetooth logs from `dmesg | grep Bluetooth` have been added to the question.
Reinstalling modules does not help.
I do not have TLP installed.

Comment: Strange... does it give you the same issues if you try to start the service and connect to the Bluetooth if you run the commands as `root`? Can you create a second user on your PC and see if you can connect to Bluetooth using the second account? Also, is it for connecting speakers/headphones? What's the content of `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf`?

Comment: Running the commands as root does not seem to effect anything, all the outputs are the same. The contents of the bluetooth.conf file can be found here: https://paste.pop-planet.info/view/57a51c94